# Unbale to preview the Report in Visual studio SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ado.net

I have created the custom data source Provider. I have edited the config file RSReportDesigner.config and RSPreviewPolicy.config. I am able to see my custom data source provider in data source list while creating the data source in SSRS (Visual Studio). While creating dataset, iam able to execute query and get data.

But, when i try to preview the report it display following error: An attempt has been made to use Data Extension 'CUSTOM_DATASOURCE' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services

Answer (score 2):

See:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2750044

and as the article instructs, be sure to also add the same xml snippet provided as the solution in the article, to the PreviewProcessingService.exe.config file that is located in %Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies folder.

This file does not have existing entries like the devenv.exe.config, but you will see an `<assemblyBinding> </assemblyBinding>`section and you can insert the xml from the article between these tags.

You may have to relaunch SQL Data Tools for the changes to take affect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Sql Server Express? Express doesn't support the full feature set of Reporting Services. [There is a list of the unsupported features on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281020.aspx), one of which is:

> The Reporting Services API extensible platform for delivery, data processing, rendering, and security is not supported

Comment: No.I am using sql server enterprise edition. I have configured my VS to point to correct sql server instance. (in tool-> option->database). Anything else is required?

Comment: Did you follow the server setup instructions from my previous post?